# How to upload only the new items to the server without updating/deleting the existing items using Microsoft Sync Framework

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework, data-synchronization

I have a data-synchronization scenario where I should upload only the new items to the server without updating/deleting the existing ones and after that download everything from the server.
I defined two **SyncOrchestrator**s (one for the upload and one for the download) with different scopes.

How can I specify that only the new items, which don't exist on the server, should be uploaded?

Edit:
***Scenario description***

The client should download everything from the server before going offline. While it is offline it can only create new records. After the client is connected to the network, it should upload the new records and after that download everything from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using information from the following article [Manipulating the change dataset in Sync Fx](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/manipulating-the-change-dataset-in-sync-fx/)

Here is my code snippet to synchronize only the new records from the client to the server

```cs
((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ChangesSelected += SelectOnlyNewRows;

void SelectOnlyNewRows(object sender, DbChangesSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (DataTable table in e.Context.DataSet.Tables)
  {
    for (int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      DataRow row = table.Rows[i];

      // We are only interested in the new rows.
      if (row.RowState != DataRowState.Added)
        table.Rows.Remove(row); // Delete the row so it doesn't get sent.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have two separate scopes defined and they both reference the same table, you'll end up with a loop. what you uploaded will be downloaded and what you downloaded will be uploaded again. sync knowledge is maintained per scope, download scope has no idea of what the upload scope has uploaded, so it doesnt know that the record shouldnt be downloaded back.

Comment: I need to upload only certain tables to the server and only the new records from these tables. After that i should download all tables. I have two scopes. First I call SyncOrchestrator.Synchronize() method with SyncDirectionOrder.Upload and the first scope. After that I change the scope and the direction to Download and call again the Synchronize method. Is this wrong? Should I use one scope with all tables and filter the tables that the client upload in the ChangesSelected event?

Comment: the ChangesSelected approach is fine. what am trying to point out is if a table is a member of two different scopes, each scope has no idea of what has been synched by the other. in your case, if a table is in the upload scope and in the download scope, the row uploaded by the upload scope will be detected as a change by the download scope and hence will be synched again. the download scope has no idea that the row came from the client

Comment: I understood the issue, but how to solve it elegantly. That's why i asked whether I should use one scope for upload and download and do the table filtering in the ChangesSelected event. It this case, there should be no loop, because there will be only one scope. The tables of the client will be filtered before upload and the tables of the server will not be filter on download. What's about this solution?